# DateTime API produces different result based on the code execution time

Tags: jodatime

I am trying to create a fixed date time using joda DateTime, surprisingly  different results are produced based on the code execution time(current system time).
Here is the code

```
 DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Brussels"));
 DateTime t1 = new DateTime().withDate(2012, OCTOBER, 28).withTime(2, 0, 0,  50);
 //Note that 2012, OCTOBER, 28, 02:00:00 is a DST swtich time in Belgium
```

The code produces two different results(TimeZone offset changes)

```
//Please note that the local time zone is CET. 
00:00:00:00 > execution time < 03:00:00  -> 2012-10-28T02:00:00.050+02:00
03:00:00:00 >= execution time =< 24:00:00  -> 2012-10-28T02:00:00.050+01:00
```

On the other hand, using a constructor produces the same result

```
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Brussels"));
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2012, OCTOBER, 28, 2, 0, 0, 50); //gives 2012-10-28T02:00:00.050+02:00
```

I have an impression that one should use the constructor instead of withDate/Time methods. But i am bit confused why DateTime can not handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the expression `new DateTime()` is sensible for the execution time so it gets eventually a different offset. **For the concrete values in question, there is an ambivalence (same local time occurs two times!).**

I think you should better choose another constructor and instead explicitly set all required field values and then call either

```
withLaterOffsetAtOverlap()
```

or

```
withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap()
```

See also the [javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) of `DateTime`.